# can't create module in bonfire using existing tables

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, ubuntu-12.04, bonfire

For some reason, I can't seem to create a bonfire module using the "existing" table option. 
Earlier, it wasn't even displaying the list of fields from my database table when I selected the option to use existing table vs. creating a new one. 
BUt I figured out that it was a permissions thing and so as a test I did the following:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/myapp
```

Now, it is querying the database and displaying all the correct fields from the table but when I click on the build button, it just keeps redisplaying the same form.

**what I've done so far:**

1. I created a test database in my database with just 2 fields.  I tried to create a module using that table... but I get the same results.
2. I've ensured that all my tables are prefixed with "bf_".  If they weren't, the system wouldn't be able to find and list all the correct fields... I think.
3. I've tested creating a new module using a new table.  That seems to work just fine.  Bonfire creates a new table in my database without any issues and also creates the correct folder structure for the module.
4. I've tried to ensure that all fields have a proper name validation rules specified. 
   In most cases, I just accepted defaults and tried to click on build.
5. changed logging settings to log everything.  but after trying to create a module and going back to the logs, there's nothing listed.

If you have any suggestions, I'd appreciate it.

**EDIT 1**

Figured out how the profiler works - i didn't realize that you had to click on the flame icon on the bottom left corner of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the issue.  there's a bug with code igniter.  found a bug report on their github site.

the post that i found was: https://github.com/ci-bonfire/Bonfire/issues/733